# "It seems [like] a random occurrence"

Tags: grammar

These seem to mean exactly the same thing. They surely sound different though, so maybe I'm missing some subtlety. Do the sentences have a different meaning?

> It seems like a random occurrence.

vs

> It seems a random occurrence.

I'm also curious about this one:

> It seems to be a random occurrence.

Comment: I've used them all synonymously at one point or another.  I would say that sentence two is the same as sentence one or three except with an understood "like" or "to be."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the sentences you wrote can be used, and would mean *to give the impression or sensation of being something or having a particular quality*.

> Dawn seemed annoyed.
>   There seems to be plenty to eat.
>   It seemed that he was determined to oppose her.

Looking on the [*Corpus of Contemporary English*](http://www.americancorpus.org) for some phrases containing *it seems*, I get the following result:

```
Phrase         |  Frequency per million
               |
               |   Spoken | Magazine | Newspaper | Academic
It seems a     |    1.11  |  0.93    |  1.09     |  0.66
It seems like  |   17.33  |  3.94    |  6.68     |  0.76
It seems that  |    9.40  |  6.30    |  5.35     | 12.01
It seems to be |    6.90  |  1.90    |  2.32     |  1.87
```

[image: Usage of "it seems"]